# Really simple question on why is the center of this distribution 75?

Tags: statistics

[image]

In a statistics problem I am doing, it asks which of the statistics appear to be unbiased estimators of the population parameter and how to be able to tell.

The solution says: Statistics A, C, and D appear to be unbiased. This is indicated by the fact that the mean of the 
estimated sampling distribution for each of these statistics is about 75, the value of the true 
population parameter.

I understand A. But I'm confused about C and D. D looks uniform so I think the center would be $\frac{100+50}{2}=75$ and that's why it's the center. Is that correct?

And Statistic C I am totally confused on.

Comment: Yes for the D you are right. Just refer to the definition of "unbiased estimator". An $\hat{x}$ estimator is unbiased if the expectation of estimator coincides with real (true) value of the mean of the parameter we are trying to estimate, for example if the target parameter $x$ has a distribution with mean $\mu$ and we estimate it with $\hat{x}$ then $\mathbb{E}\{\hat{x}\}=\mu$. In the case of C, please notice that distribution is symmetric around  $75$ and thus the mean is $75$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes... your reasoning for D seems correct to me. The key is just to find a way to claim the mean or average of the estimator is $75$.

For C, notice that there are high points on both ends. However, these high points "balance" each other out and so on average you could expect to get something around 75. As the comment mentions, this can also be stated by claiming the distribution is symmetric around 75.

If you actually wanted to compute the mean, suppose $x_k$ is the (normalized) height of the bar corresponding to $k$, then the mean can be approximated as
$$\sum_k k x_k$$